# What is the difference with brackets [] and without them in Angular HTML?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I used reactive form in angular and put radio-button to my HTML code.
First I put code like below and used 'default' key word to on check box select default. But I second load same form default check not visible. In type script form ,I will patch value 'true' to form controller as default.

```
<mat-radio-button  value="true" id="1" [checked]="true" />
<mat-radio-button  value="false" id="2"  />
```

After I changed it like below.

```
<mat-radio-button  [value]="true" id="1" />
<mat-radio-button  [value]="false" id="2" />
```

now it worked as expected. Need some expert help to , what happen this different way in internally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets tells Angular that input bound property is an expression and needs to be evaluated. Eg this:

```
<mat-radio-button [prop]="prop" />
```

Will try to access a `prop` variable on its scope and get its value, while

```
<mat-radio-button prop="prop" />
```

will simply add `prop` attribute to the element with a string value assigned

Comment: In HTML if you define an attribute without a value, e.g. `disabled`, then this attribute is assumed to be boolean true. What happens in Angular if you define it as `[attrName]` without assigning a value?

Answer (score 1):

`value="true"` bind the `string` 'true' instead of a boolean value.

`[value]="true"` bind to the boolean `true`. With bracket [], Angular bind to a literal (boolean, string, number, etc.) or to anything from your component that is public or to template variable.

`value="true"` is the same as `[value]="'true'"`.